# How to print index: value when loop a list in Python

Tags: python

In C#:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>() { "AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE" };
for (int i = 0; i < stringList.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + stringList[i]);
```

Output:

```
0: AAAA
1: BBBB
2: CCCC
3: DDDD
4: EEEE
```

In Python:

```
stringList = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"]
for i, string in enumerate(stringList):
    print(i + ": " + string)
```

I want output same as the output above, but there is error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: `i` is not a string, but an `int`. Use `str(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must use str() as per @RoadRunner comment, it will look like the C# which I want

```
stringList = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"]
for i in range(len(stringList)):
    print(str(i) + ": " + stringList[i])
```

or

```
stringList = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"]
for i, string in enumerate(stringList):
    print(str(i) + ": " + string)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code, Hope this helps:

```
stringList = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"]
for i, string in enumerate(stringList):
    print(i ,": ", string)
```

Ouput will be :

```
0 :  AAAA
1 :  BBBB
2 :  CCCC
3 :  DDDD
4 :  EEEE
```

Comment: Or `print("{0}: {1}".format(i,string))` to autmaitilly string format index integer

Comment: @gtalarico , yes you can also use this method. It is upto your convenience. :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess your code is just fine, maybe just a bit modify it:

```
stringList = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"]
for i, string in enumerate(stringList):
    print(f'{i}:  {string}')
```

#### Output

```
0:  AAAA
1:  BBBB
2:  CCCC
3:  DDDD
4:  EEEE
```

You can also write with list comprehension, if you like:

```
stringList = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"]
[print(f'{i}:  {string}') for i, string in enumerate(stringList)]
```

Or you can simply build your `output` first and then print only once:

```
stringList = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"]
output = ''
for i, string in enumerate(stringList):
    output += f'{i}: {string}\n'

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `while` loop:

```
stringList = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"]
i = 0
while i < len(stringList):
    print(str(i) + ": " + stringList[i])
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Forgetting `i += 1` at the end. Also, whats wrong with a `for` loop? In this case the list is fixed, so a `for` loop is probably the better option. A `while` loop is better in situations where you don't know how many elements your going to process.

Comment: @RoadRunner I don't know what the most "Pythonic" way to do this is, but my answer is probably closest to the for loop syntax used in the OP's quoted C# code.